# Number of loops in permutations

Tags: probability, permutations, puzzle

From the famous prisoners problem there are *n* labelled boxes and inside each the relative number. These are randomly mixed so that you don’t know which number is inside each box. How can I compute  the distribution of the loops lengths given *n*? Where a loop is defined as the path that emerge following from a certain box the number inside it and so on until you reach again the first one.

This is a link about the puzzle and a solution using a simulation 
https://youtu.be/a1DUUnhk3uE

Comment: Clarify... are you asking for the probability that in a randomly selected permutation that there exists at least one cycle of length greater than $\frac{n}{2}$ (*or equivalently no cycles of length greater than $\frac{n}{2}$*)?  Are you asking for the distribution of the length of the cycle that a randomly selected element in a randomly selected permutation has?  Are you asking for the distribution of the length of a randomly selected cycle in a randomly selected permutation?  Only the first is actually relevant for solving the linked puzzle.

Comment: Actually the puzzle says that all the prisoners have to find “their” number to be saved. The optimal strategy if everyone has n/2 possible attempts is to open first the box with your number and then follow the loops. This is true because the chance of having a loop shorter than n/2 is around 30%. You can show this with a simple simulation but I’d like to obtain this result analytically. In particular the distribution of path lengths or the distribution of successful attempts (out of n) where at n I expect a peak with as I said around 30%

Comment: I am well familiar with the puzzle, it doesn't need to be described to me.  What I needed described was *which* distribution you were interested in specifically.  The only relevant distributions to showing the result stated in the video is the probability of the first event from my first comment or the distribution I describe in my second comment.  The prisoners will survive if and only if there is no cycle of length strictly greater than $\frac{n}{2}$.  However, the way you worded your problem made it sound like you might be interested in one of the irrelevant distributions instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [100 prisoners 100 boxes problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1338318/100-prisoners-100-boxes-problem)

Comment: I’m sorry I wasn’t sure which was the problem. But yes I’m interested in how to compute the probability of your first comment. Moreover I’d like to compute the distribution of loop lengths which as far as I can understand it makes sense.

Comment: "*the distribution of* **loop lengths**"  Of *what* loop lengths?  Of the longest loop in a randomly selected permutation?  Of the length of the loop that a randomly selected element is in in a randomly selected permutation?  Of the length of a randomly selected loop is in a randomly selected permutation?  As stated already, these are all different questions with different answers, and only the first of them is actually relevant to the calculations in the puzzle you are interested in.

Comment: Distribution of the loop length picked a random initial box from a random initial condition given n boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the single question:

> What is the probability the longest loop is length $k$, where $k \gt \frac n2$?

This condition means if there is any loop of length $k$ then any other loop cannot be longer than $n-k < k$.

In total there are $n!$ possible patterns.

It should not be difficult to see that of these, there are $(n-1)!$ patterns where the only loop is of length $n$, making the probability of this event $\frac1n$ as mentioned in the video.

It is not much harder to see that  there are ${n \choose k} (k-1)! (n-k)! =\frac{n!}{k}$ patterns where the longest loop is of length $k$: you choose the $k$ involved, put them in a loop and then do anything possible with the rest.  So the probability of this happening is $\frac1k$

This means that the probability that the longest loop exceeds $\frac n2$ is related to [Harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number): $$\sum\limits_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor +1}^n \frac1k = H(n) - H(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)$$ and for large $n$ this is going to have a limit of $\log_e(2)\approx 0.6931472$; the probability the longest loop is not more than $\frac n2$ then has a limit of $1-\log_e(2)\approx 0.3068528$ close to the $0.31$ mentioned in the video

---

It is possible to find the probability that the longest loop is $k$ when $1 \le k\le \frac n2$, but I suspect perhaps not in a closed form.  In that case you either want the first loop to be length $k$ and the other loops to be shorter than $k$ or the first loop to be of length less than or equal to $k$ and the longest other loop to be exactly $k$, which gives the recurrence $$P_n(k)=\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} P_{n-k}(i) + \sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} P_{n-j}(k) \right)$$  while when $\frac n2 < k \le n$ we have $P_n(k) =\frac1k$, from earlier.

Clearly $P_n(1)=\frac1{n!}$ and calculating the probabilities up to $n=10$ gives the following table:

```
      k:   1         2         3          4      5    6   7   8   9   10
n:                                                                       
1         1                                                             
2         1/2       1/2                                                 
3         1/6       1/2       1/3                                       
4         1/24      3/8       1/3        1/4                            
5         1/120     5/24      1/3        1/4    1/5                     
6         1/720     5/48      5/18       1/4    1/5  1/6                
7         1/5040    11/240    7/36       1/4    1/5  1/6 1/7            
8         1/40320   109/5760  23/180     7/32   1/5  1/6 1/7 1/8        
9         1/362880  97/13440  127/1620   27/160 1/5  1/6 1/7 1/8 1/9     
10        1/3628800 211/80640 1013/22680 61/480 9/50 1/6 1/7 1/8 1/9 1/10
```

where, for example, $P_{10}(4)= \frac{1}{10}\left(\frac{1}{720}+ \frac{5}{48}+\frac{5}{18}+\frac14 + \frac14 +\frac{7}{32}+\frac{27}{160}\right)= \frac{61}{480}$

Comment: Could you please explain the derivation of the formula for $P_n(k)$ in more details including for example how the first, second and further loops are defined?

Comment: @user: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k-1} \frac{1}{n} P_{n-k}(i)$ is the probability that the first loop is of length $k$ and the other loops shorter than $k$ (summed over the length $i$ of the longest other loop), while $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n} P_{n-j}(k)$ is the probability that the first loop is of length less than or equal to $k$ and the longest other loop is exactly $k$ (summed over the length $j$ of the first loop).

Comment: You have described this already in your answer. I asked about the derivation of these expressions (= why this is the described probability). Particularly, where does factor $\frac1n$ come from?

Comment: @user It is difficult to avoid repetition: I derived it by noticing the longest loop is of length $k$ either when the first loop is of length $k$ and all the others are shorter or when the longest of the others is of length $k$ and the first loop is not longer.  Then I took the combined probability.   I noticed this when trying to calculate the table, for example with $P_4(2)$ and $P_6(3)$ and then the other terms.

Comment: I have succeeded to derive the expression (and upvoted your answer). But I do not think that any reader is able to repeat this especially in terms of probabilities (I was not able). So it would be great if you add the derivation in the answer (of course I see that the question is closed by a correct reason and that your answer is obviously beyond the scope of the question).